# Eiruv in Jerusalem

Tags: yerushalayim-jerusalem, eruv-chatzerot

I will be travelling to Israel in a few weeks, and expect to be in Jerusalem for Shabbos. I've been trying to find out about the eiruv in Jerusalem (I've heard that there are two, one certified by the Badat"z and one by the Rabbinate):

Does anyone know the boundaries of the(se) eiruv(in)? Can one carry across Bar Ilan using the eiruv? And (please, no politics, just a straightforward answer!) who certifies which eiruv?

Comment: Hello WJ and welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for the interesting question! I hope you'll look around and find other Q&A of interest and stay learning with us.

Comment: check out http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/shabat/eruv/shaar-2.htm

Comment: Thanks @mbloch for the link, it's helpful (or will be once I figure it out:)) - but if anyone has more info I'd still appreciate.

Answer (score 2):

The Badatz Eruv is quite smaller that the Rabbanut Eruv in the link provided by mbloch, primarly serving chareidi areas.

VERY general boundries/areas in the Badatz eruv: (Counter-clockwise) Ramot, Ramat shlomo, Ramat Eskol, French Hill, Sderot Bar Lev, The Old City, Mamilla, king George, Sharei Chesed/Rechavia, Does not include any part of Gan Sacher or Givat Ram, Bayit Vegan, Har Nof, Givat Shaul, Matersdorf/sorotzkin/Ezras Torah...

Try to get hold of the Chareidi Phone Book (www.hamadrich-hacharedi.co.il) which containes the map.

And those who carry in the Badatz Eruv do cross Bar Illan.